# Excel vba, Changing cell references in formula to point to different cell location

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I am trying to move (offset) only parts of formula column location to a different column location by a specified amount of columns. The formula cells change from sheet to sheet.  I have thousands of formulas that all have different cell locations. So I prefer some kind of vba macro solution. This is original formula:

```
=IF(AND($A$9=1,GH10=GT12),0,IF(AND($A$9=2,GI10=GS13),0,IF(AND($A$9=3,GJ10=GR14),0,1)))
```

and want it changed to this:

```
=IF(AND($A$9=1,GI10=GT12),0,IF(AND($A$9=2,GJ10=GS13),0,IF(AND($A$9=3,GK10=GR14),0,1)))
```

this is by one column over, but only the numerator (GH10 -> GI10 and GI10 -> GJ10, etc).  And have the same constant Row number.

I found this code (below), It allows me to pick from a drop down box how many columns to move(NOT NECESSARY as long as I can enter it in the code manually), but this also changes the denominator of the formula. (NOTE:I CAN NOT add $ to the parts of the formula I don't want changed. The formula has to stay dynamic).

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim nbr As Long, cel As Range, cels As Range, sh As Worksheet
    Set cels = Selection

    nbr = CLng(InputBox("Enter offset:"))

    Set sh = Worksheets.Add

    For Each cel In cels

        If cel.HasFormula Then

            sh.Cells(cel.Row, cel.Column + nbr).FormulaR1C1 = cel.FormulaR1C1
            cel.Formula = sh.Cells(cel.Row, cel.Column + nbr).Formula

        End If

    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        sh.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

This is for one cell at a time.  If there is working VBA code can it accommodate a selected Range as oppose to single cell at a time?

Comment: I know you asked for a VBA solution, but did you consider using `OFFSET`, as in `Offset(GH10,,cell_reference)` where the cell reference would contain the column offset for that sheet.

Comment: GH10 is only used in 1 out of thousand formulas; next sheet will have a different cell pointer.

Comment: Why don't you use `Find & Replace` with `Formula Option`, or I can suggest VBA for `Find & Replace`. Tell me in how may Rows you need to change `GJ10` with `GK10` ?

Comment: in only 1 Row, on 1000+ sheets.  GJ10 is only in one formula out of  thousand formulas spread out through thousand sheets.  I would have to input Find thousand times and know the cell to input into Find.  I just want to offset the "numerator" part of the test (ie:GJ10=GR14) only GJ10 offset by 1+ column to (GK10=GR14).

Comment: Why not search and replace `GJ` with `GK` in the formulas of the appropriate column? If you don't want to do it manually, it can easily be automated with `Range.Replace`.

Comment: BUT, GJ is ONLY IN 1 FORMULA on 1 sheet!  There are 1000+ formulas and sheets that don't have GJ. With replace I would need to type in the appropriate cell in order to change the next formula. Needs to be VBA script from my understanding.

Comment: I appreciate your input, but the VBA would have to be something like this:     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(AND(cel.Row,Cel.Column = 1,(cel.Row,cel.Column + "1" = cel.Row, cel.Column)),0,IF ...  which does not work.

Comment: SOLUTION FOUND USING REPLACE AND THEN RUNNING ABOVE MACRO.  THANKS